# Android getSupportFragmentManager with FragmentActivity

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment

I'm working with this Activity :

```
public class ViatgeDetallViewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ViatgeDetallViewFragment fragment;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_view);


            fragment = new ViatgeDetallViewFragment();        
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.activity_fragment_view, fragment)  
                    .commit();


        }
    .....
    }
```

The class ViatgeDetallViewFragment is this :

```
public class ViatgeDetallViewFragment extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    public ViatgeDetallViewFragment() {
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }


    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_view, container, false);


        SupportMapFragment mapFragment =
                (SupportMapFragment)
                        getSupportFragmentManager()
                                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);


        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        ...

}
```

With the a simple layout for the activity being :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/activity_view"
    >

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/tlbMenuView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/activity_fragment_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

And the fragment_view being :

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/layout_fragment_view" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="View"
        />       
    <fragment
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/fragment_view_map"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"></fragment>

</LinearLayout>
```

The problem comes in "ViatgeDetallViewActivity" when i try to add the fragment :

```
 fragment = new ViatgeDetallViewFragment();        
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.activity_fragment_view, fragment)  
                    .commit();
```

I get the following error :

```
Error:(68, 21) error: no suitable method found for add(int,ViatgeDetallViewFragment)
method FragmentTransaction.add(Fragment,String) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; int cannot be converted to Fragment)
method FragmentTransaction.add(int,Fragment) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; ViatgeDetallViewFragment cannot be converted to Fragment)
```

I've tried the same exact code but with the fragment class extending "fragment" and not "FragmentActivity" and everything went ok.

Comment: If i where to do that i would get problems with the next line SupportMapFragment mapFragment =
                (SupportMapFragment)
                        getSupportFragmentManager()
                                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);   Iwnat to work with a google Map, that's why i need the class to extend FragmentActivity

Comment: Made the changes, ViatgeDetallViewFragment extends fragment, and the layout has a supportMapfragment instead. Doesen't seem to work. The same problem as before + a new error in ViatgeDetallViewFragment when  i try to get the " SupportMapFragment"

Comment: That seems to work! Indeed, changing the import got the error solved !

Answer (score 0):

You should extend **Fragment** class instead of **FragmentActivity**.